# Quarkus application is giving error while starting up

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, sasl, java-21, vertx-kafka-client

`I am trying to start the quarkus application which also has a kafka producer class in one of the packages ,  I have checked all the kafka related properties and environment variables which is fine no issues with that but quarkus application is giving an error while starting and I am not able to debug why that is happening

logs:-

```
22:16:32 ERROR [io.qu.ru.bo.StartupActionImpl] (Quarkus Main Thread) Error running Quarkus:       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:98)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.SslConfigs.<clinit>(SslConfigs.java:80)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.withClientSslSupport(ConfigDef.java:450)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.<clinit>(ConsumerConfig.java:559)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:665)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:646)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:626)
at ca.bell.eventpump.stream.KafkaTopicConsumer.<init>(KafkaTopicConsumer.java:123)
at ca.bell.eventpump.stream.EventPump.initializeTopicConsumer(EventPump.java:142)
at ca.bell.eventpump.stream.EventPump.initialize(EventPump.java:228)
at ca.bell.BIPManager.startEventPumpConsumer(BIPManager.java:168)
at ca.bell.BIPManager.startEventPumpConsumers(BIPManager.java:140)
at ca.bell.BIPManager.main(BIPManager.java:54)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:199)
at java.base/java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:221)
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Java.parseVersion(Java.java:29)
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Java.<clinit>(Java.java:25)
... 18 more

22:16:32 INFO  [io.qu.de.de.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start live reload endpoint to    recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
22:16:32 ERROR [io.qu.de.de.DevModeMain] (main) Quarkus dev mode failed to start:   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at io.vertx.core.impl.cpu.CpuCoreSensor.determineProcessors(CpuCoreSensor.java:65)
at io.vertx.core.impl.cpu.CpuCoreSensor.availableProcessors(CpuCoreSensor.java:58)
at io.vertx.core.VertxOptions.<clinit>(VertxOptions.java:38)
at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder.initialize(VertxCoreRecorder.java:243)
at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$VertxSupplier.get(VertxCoreRecorder.java:570)
at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$VertxSupplier.get(VertxCoreRecorder.java:552)
at   io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.startServerAfterFailedStart(VertxHttpRecorder.java:191)
at   io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.handleFailedInitialStart(VertxHttpHotRe placementSetup.java:52)
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.startupFailed(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:1047)
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:168)
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:424)
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:64)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:136)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:93)
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:145)
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.ExecUtils.<clinit>(ExecUtils.java:62)
... 16 more
```

Comment: seems a compatibility problem between libraries and java; just downgrade to java-17 or upgrade quarkus to 3.5+ for java-21 support

Comment: Looking at the NPEs thrown from the kafka-clients and vertx, you seem to be running on a JVM that doesn't provide some system properties, or you've explicitly removed them with `System.clearProperty`